# Nhibernate and MS Access

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, ms-access, orm

1. Can NHibernate be used as ORM tool for MS Access? 
      We are using Nhibernate to access Sql Server, so wondering if it can be reused.
2. If it can be used how has the experience been?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the details of [using NHibernate with MS Access](http://www.hibernate.org/361.html#A4).  I personally haven't done this, as MS Access doesn't include main full database options like stored procedures, etc, so I typically avoid it.

Comment: When you say "MS Access" you mean "Jet".

Comment: True.  I used MS Access to keep it in the same form as the question, but it's really using NHibernate with the JET db engine Access uses.

Answer (score 10):

I have used NHibernate with Access. Based on my experience,

- I recommend using NHibernate.
- I recommend avoiding Access.

If you need a file-based in-process mini-database, there are a number of options available, including [SQL Server CE](http://sqlserverce.org/) (Microsoft, proprietary), [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) (free-open-source), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (free-open-source). NHibernate supports all these database engines (although I have not had a chance to use them).

Comment: The reason we want to go for MS Access is the because we are mainly writing MS Office Plug in related applications. Since MS Access comes with Office installation we don't have to install some other database in hundreds of machines (on every client laptop!). Anyway why should we not use Access?

Comment: You don't have to "install" SQLite in your client's machines. All you have to do is package the sqlite .dll file with your mail plugin .dll and you're good to go.

Comment: I assume Firebird and SQLServerCE work the same but I'm not sure. But that's what makes these things "embedded" databases - you can "embed" them right into your software!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid MS Access ? MS Access is free as database format so I can't see any advantage using other format.

Answer (score 3):

It can be used with MS Access. The experience is like any other experience using MS Access as a database for your application, you wish you used something else.